# How to solve java multi inheritance?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface

Lets say i have a base class Entity with variables for position.

```
public class Entity {
    private int position;
}
```

Now i want a classes that have variables for speed, health, damage and any combination of those. like:

```
public class MovingAndHealth extends Entity {
    private int speed;
    private int health;
}
```

Is there a way to do this or do i have to make all variations manually?

Comment: You have to do it manually

Comment: Are you sure that's a desirable design to begin with? I mean, do you really need classes that are *that* specific?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca This is just an example. i would like to use 10+ specific variables for each class type.

Comment: Implement interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Second option is not to inherit, but create a class which has inside the instances of all your "child classes"

Answer (score 0):

You can only extend one class, but multiple inheritance in Java is achieved with interfaces.